# Private property can't access in this class in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Codes are below

```
export class HighlightDirective implements OnInit {
    private _defaultColor: 'green';

    ngOnInit():any {
        console.log(this._defaultColor);
    }
}
```

I can't access `_defaultColor` property

Comment: Are you calling `ngOnInit` yourself from somewhere?

Comment: @ScottMarcus if it's declared at class level instead of method level, it is an instance property not a local variable.

Comment: What is the code that you're executing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely (with all the outputs necessary to understand)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better to declare your variable like this.

```
private _defaultColor: string = 'green';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error which is causing this. You're assigning `green` as the type of the variable rather than the value.

So changing to `private _defaultColor: string = 'green';` will solve that issue. Another thing to point out is that `private` variables cannot be accessed from the template when using AOT. So if that is a requirement also you need to change it to `public` or remove it (since it defaults to public if not specified).